# C shared library problems

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a shared library called `-lrfc7539`
with the structure below:

```
rfc7539.o: rfc7539.c chacha20poly1305.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

chacha20poly1305.o: chacha20poly1305.c chacha20.o poly1305.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

chacha20.o: chacha_merged.c
    $(CC) -fPIC $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

poly1305.o: poly1305-donna.c
    $(CC) -fPIC $(CFLAGS) -DPOLY1305_16BIT -c -o $@ $<

rfc7539_test: rfc7539.o chacha20poly1305.o poly1305.o chacha20.o

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f rfc7539_test
```

I then do this command `gcc -shared -o lrfc7539.so *.o` to create `.so` file 
Is there a better practice for my makefile to be able to do this automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a target in your makefile that runs the gcc command you gave.  If this library is the main output, make an `all` target pointing to in.

```
all: lrfc7539.so

lrfc7539.so: rfc7539.o chacha20poly1305.o chacha20.o poly1305.o 
    gcc -shared -o $@ *.o
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for all day.

Comment: @YoussefRekik Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make a rule with that target:

```
librfc7539.so: rfc7539.o chacha20poly1305.o poly1305.o chacha20.o
    $(LINK.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) -shared $^  $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

I copied the command from `make --print-data-base` (you could update your other commands likewise).  You may need to add `-fPIC` to `LDFLAGS`, too.

I called your library `librfc7539.so` so that you can link to it using `-lrfc7539` - I think that's what you're wanting.

---

I believe it's best practice to explicitly specify the object files you intend to link, but some like to assume that every source file must be compiled and linked:

```
sources := $(wildcard *.c)
librfc7539.so: $(sources:.c=.o)
```

This wouldn't work for you, though, unless you renamed the source files that are compiled to differently-named object files.

---

I note that it's strange that your object files depend on other object files.  That shouldn't be the case, although they may need dependencies on some *header* files.

Here's a complete Makefile (assuming GNU Make):

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS += -fPIC

LDFLAGS += -fPIC

%.so: LDFLAGS += -shared

all: rfc7539_test librfc7539.so

librfc7539.so: rfc7539.o chacha20poly1305.o poly1305.o chacha20.o
    $(LINK.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

rfc7539_test: rfc7539.o chacha20poly1305.o poly1305.o chacha20.o
    $(LINK.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

# Default %.o:%.c rule works, except for these files with misnamed sources:

chacha20.o: chacha_merged.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

poly1305.o: poly1305-donna.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

# Specific flags for this source file
poly1305.o: CFLAGS += -DPOLY1305_16BIT

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    @$(RM) *.o
    @$(RM) rfc7539_test

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```